# Logout Error using /sap/public/bc/icf/logoff from SAP HCP

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use the standard logoff Service /sap/public/bc/icf/logoff for logoff on custom button, When i run this

https://webidetesting3880479-XXXXXtrial.dispatcher.hanatrial.ondemand.com/sap/public/bc/icf/logoff

It is giving HTTP Status 404 - Not Found error.

Even tried

window.location.href = "/sap/public/bc/icf/logoff?redirectURL=/sap/bc/bsp/sap/zpocnapp/index.htm";

Best regards,
Rohit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Created a Custom login and Logoff Page now and Handled this using writing own gateway Service.

Answer (score 0):

> /sap/public/bc/icf/logoff

This is a serviceof your SAP-Backend!
It doesn't exist in your WebIDE

Comment: I am calling this service as other services, will it not work>

Comment: Your application has to be hosted from the SAP-System and not by WebIDE